# object oriented perl, set hash values

Tags: perl, class, oop, hash

I have a class:

```
sub new {

    my ($class, $name) = @_;

    my $self = {        
        _ids => [],
        _devices => {}       
    };

    bless ($self, $class);

    return $self;

}
```

I pass the subroutine an array, and say:

```
sub Importids {

    my ($self, $id_ref) = @_;

    foreach $id (@{$id_ref})
    {        
        push(@{$self->{_ids}}, $id);            
    }

}
```

I further would like to add into this function that I initialize the hash, but am having a hell of a time doing this.
In the end I want that my hash looks like this for a number of ids:

```
_device --> id1|
                --> status --> 0/1
            id2|
                --> status --> 0/1
```

where the id is the key.

I tried to do this in the function as follows:

```
sub Importids {

    my ($self, $id_ref) = @_;

    foreach $id (@{$id_ref})
    {    
        push(@{$self->{_ids}}, $id);        
    }

    foreach my $id_value(@{$self->{_ids}})
    {
        $self->{_devices}{$id_value}{'status'} = 0;
    }

}
```

but when I go to check the contents as follows, it returns only the hex dump of the hashes

```
for my $hash_key (keys %{$self->{_devices}})
{
    print $self->{_devices}{$hash_key};
    #print keys % {$self->_devices}};
}
```

gives:

```
HASH(0x....)
HASH(0x....)
...
...
HASH(0x....)
```

however, when I try:

```
for my $hash_key (keys %{$self->{_devices}})
{
    print $self->{_devices}->{$hash_key}->{'status'};

}
```

I get what I want:

```
0
0
...
0
```

How should I access the keys and also add an additional field such as status2''?

Comment: Here `print $self->{_devices}{$hash_key};` you _are_ printing the hashref. Here `$self->{_devices}->{$hash_key}->{'status'};`, which is the same as `$self->{_devices}{$hash_key}{'status'};`, you are actually printing the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**    The short first part refers to the original question, which changed in the meanwhile.

---

When you are setting up the hash, you iterate over the array with id's, using `$id_value` as the variable. Then you assign it to a *non-existent* key

```
$self->{_devices}{ids} = $id_value;  # what is 'ids' string?
```

Thus a key `'ids'` will be added and each assignment will overwrite the previous. Also, note that this way the `$id_value` (would) become values, not keys, contrary to what the question states.

What is supposed to be in `$self->{_devices}` ?  If keys are id's, to be "*initialized*", say to `0`

```
foreach my $id (@$id_ref)
{
    push @{$self->{_ids}}, $id;
    $self->{_devices}{$id} = 0;
}
```

There are more compact and clearer ways but let's first clarify if this is intended.

---

*Update to clarification in comments*

The objective is to construct a structure

```
_device --> id1 --> status --> 0/1
            id2 --> status --> 0/1
            ...
```

We also want to be able to read/change values, and add another kind of 'status'.  Let us first forget about classes and build this data structure.
See  tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and the data-structures cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

In Perl we can use a hash reference for this, with further nested hash references

```
my $hashref = { 
    'id1' => { 
        'status'  => 0,
        'status2' => 0
    }, 
    'id2' => { 
        'status'  => 0,
        'status2' => 0,
    },
    # ...
};
```

The  *anonymous hash* `{ status => 0, status2 => 0 }` is assigned as a value to keys `'id1', 'id2'`. Being a (nameless) reference to a hash it is loosely called *hashref* (like `\%hash` is, too).  Any reference is a scalar, a single value, so a hashref can be assigned to a key. This is how we build nested (complex) data structures, using *references*.  They are much like pointers.

We can populate it in code like so

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;  # to see our structures

my @ids = qw(id1 id2 id3);

my $hashref;

foreach my $id (@ids) {
    foreach my $stat ('status', 'status2') {
        $hashref->{$id}{$stat} = 0;
    }
}

print Dumper($hashref);
```

Strictly, we'd need to dereference at each level, `$hashref->{$id}->{$stat}`, but a notational shortcut allows us to omit all other than the first one (since that then can't mean anything else).

The keys `$id` are added to the hash once encountered (*autovivified*). So are the keys `$stat` in the nested hash(ref) (assigned the value `0` above). We print and change values by

```
$hashref->{$id}{'status'} = 1;

print "$hashref->{$id}{'status'}\n";
```

We can add yet another 'status' the same way, `$hashref->{$id}{'status3'} = 0`.

Now to the class. We use only one 'status' field. Please add suitable error checking.

```
sub Importids 
{
    my ($self, $id_ref) = @_;

    foreach my $id (@{$id_ref}) 
    {    
        push @{$self->{_ids}}, $id;
        $self->{_devices}{$id}{'status'} = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

How do we change values for given ids?  Let's first come up with an interface. With ids in `$id` variables and their new values-to-be in `$val`'s, we can imagine a call

```
$obj->set_status( { $id1 => $val1, $id2 => $val2 } );             
# Or
$obj->set_status( $new_vals_for_ids_hashref );
```

This builds a hashref inside the call or uses one built previously.
Then here is a method for it

```
sub set_status 
{
    my ($self, $rhstat) = @_;  # check for $rhstat

    foreach my $id (keys %$rhstat) {
        $self->{_devices}{$id} = $rhstat->{$id};
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This adds new ids if they are not already there, or overwrites the values for the existing ones. We can make this same sub be the getter as well -- when nothing is passed in

```
sub status 
{
    my ($self, $rstat) = @_; 
    
    return $self->{_devices} if not defined $rstat; 

    foreach my $id (keys %$rstat) {
        $self->{_devices}{$id} = $rstat->{$id};
    }
    return $self->{_devices};
}
```

with intended uses `my $devices = $obj->status();` or with an argument.  Since we now return data in one case we do the same when ids are added/changed as well, for interface  consistency.

You can add 'status' fields similarly,

```
$obj->add_status( [ qw(status2 status3) ] );
```

where `[ ... ]` is an *anonymous array*, with a method

```
sub add_status 
{
    my ($self, $rstats) = @_;

    foreach my $stat (@$rstats) 
    {
        foreach my $id (@{$self->{_ids}}) 
        {
            $self->{_devices}{$id}{$stat} = 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

We can make this method also optionally take and set values for new keys, by passing *either* a hashref with key-value pairs (add keys and set them), *or* an arrayref as above, what can be checked in the method (see [ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref)).

Note that there are more compact ways to work with lists of keys/values.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood exactly what my assignment statement was doing. Where you state that I assign it to a non-existent key, I understood that I'm assigning a set of unique keys.
For each of these unique keys, I want a field 'status', which by default I set to '0'. Could I ask how you would make this assignment, and further, how you could later change the value of 'status' to '1' by the use of setters/getters (if that's at all practical). Could I also ask how I'd push an additional field, say, 'status2', and give that a default value? Appreciate it, regards.

Comment: @Plexus Yes, it seemed to me that you got it backwards. "_Assigning a key_" is somewhat ambiguous -- you can "assign (a value) to a key", or "add a key" to a hash (with some value).  If values in your `_ids` arrayref are supposed to be become keys in `_devices` hashref, then you do what I posted, `$self->{_devicess}{$id} = 0`.  Then the hashref `_devices` got a key `$id` which has value `0` associated with it.  Let's first clear this up -- is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Plexus  But if you want that each `$id` (element of arrayref `_ids`) is a key that has an associated label `'status'`, that itself with has a value, then you need to add another level to your hashref, so `$self->{_devices}{$id}{'status'} = 0`.  Note that what you had before the edit, `$self->{_devices}{ids} = $id_value;` added a key which is the string `'ids'`. (That's not what you wanted, I think.)  What you have now, `$self->{_devices} = $id_value;` makes it into something yet else, a hashref `{  '_devices' => $id_value }`.  Check out these messages and let me know.

Comment: @Plexus  I'd advise a good read through the tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and the data-structures cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  But let me know so once we clear up what you need I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Apologies if this is unclear at the moment, I'm trying to be clear here. Yes, the incoming items from my array ref are to become keys in _devices. Further, for each key, I want to give a label 'status' (which I have failed to detail here), and then set this 'status' property to a default value '0'. Between the key given from the array and the value '0'  I need 'status', and I would like to at a later time push some other parameter at the same level as 'status', perhaps 'status2'. Can you suggest a way that I can view the hash and make these additions? Thank you zdim

Comment: @Plexus Alright, I got it now.  It was in your post but it just wasn't clear (for me).  I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @Plexus  I have added to the answer.  First a note on hashrefs -- this is what you're missing.  I'd suggest that you read up on it, from given references or your favorite material.  Then there's implementation of methods you ask for.  Note that this is a little simple, in particular with no error checking at all.  Let me know.

Comment: @Plexus  Something you probably don't realize.  When you keep changing what you posted it is really difficult to answer.  And any answers that are already there may well be invalidated.  It is better to _add_ to your question, leaving the original statement -- and code in particular -- intact.

Comment: Right! I'll add to my statement the next time, but everything I was inquiring about has been thoroughly answered here. The line: foreach my $stat ('status', 'status2')  was unintuitive, but your instruction has greatly made sense of how to handle hashes - thank you for your help, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Plexus Great, glad it helped :).  A couple more notes.  (1) The loop `for  (@array)` needs _a list_, not necessarily an array.  So you can say `for ('a', 'b')` -- or `for (qw(a b))`.   Any good list will do :).  So you can also do things like `for (map { split } @array)` etc. (This breaks array elems by space so you then iterate over words.) One shouldn't push this of course.  (2) One is allowed to drop quotes here `$hash{'str'}` to `$hash{str}`. Syntactic shortcut. (3) These are the same: `$rh->{a}->{b}->{c}` and `$rh->{a}{b}{c}`.  You'll find it in `perldsc` at the link in my answer.